# can we save card information from razorpay into local database?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, payment-gateway, razorpay

I am implementing Razorpay payment gateway into an eCommerce site, the requirement is whatever Debit/Credit card information users enter should be saved in the database, is it possible to save the information into the database?

Comment: Can you share some code from where you want to send the data to the database? Razorpay payment gateway is a vast topic and surely you cannot expect people to go through it an provide a solution. This is not the standard of stackoverflow.

Comment: Have you got the information you want to save?If so,you can try to use efcore to  save the information into database.Here is a [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro?view=aspnetcore-6.0) about efcore with .net core project.